# S3 bucket access denied from Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload build files from Jenkins to S3 Bucket. I wanted only Cloudfront & the user `deployer` to have access to the bucket, the policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::samplebucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/deployer"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::samplebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::samplebucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is not allowing the `deployer` to upload objects to S3. Whereas if i set the bucket access to public, i am able to successfully upload the objects from Jenkins. I don't want my buckets to be public.

Comment: What are you using to do the deployment to s3, i.e. which plugin or method?

Comment: S3 publisher plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin

Comment: What about ARNs? Are these proper? And for cloud front, arn seems to be invalid.

Comment: No They are proper, I have configured it from cloudfront itself to allow read access to the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a user with Access Key and Secret Key to access the bucket with full permissions, but checked `Use IAM Role` in Jenkins -> Configure System -> Amazon S3 Profiles. Just uncheck , you are good to go. Probably i need to check it only when using a role.

[image]